# Throttling with Redis Only on Production in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redis, throttling, rate-limiting

### Background

Out of the box, Laravel provides two middleware that can be used for rate limiting (throttling):

```
\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class
\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequestsWithRedis::class
```

As the documentation states, if you are using Redis as the cache driver, you can change the mapping in the `Kernel.php` like so:

```
/**
 * The application's middleware aliases.
 *
 * Aliases may be used instead of class names to conveniently assign middleware to routes and groups.
 *
 * @var array<string, class-string|string>
 */
protected $middlewareAliases = [
    // ...
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequestsWithRedis::class
    // ...
];
```

### The Issue

The issue with this is that the above is not dynamic, dependent on the environment. For instance, on my `staging` and `production` environments, I utilise Redis, but on my `local` and `development` environments, I do not.

### Potential Solution

There is an obvious dirty fix, something **like** this (`Kernel.php`):

```
/**
 * The application's middleware aliases.
 *
 * Aliases may be used instead of class names to conveniently assign middleware to routes and groups.
 *
 * @var array<string, class-string|string>
 */
protected $middlewareAliases = [
    // ...
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class
    // ...
];

/**
 * Create a new HTTP kernel instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application  $app
 * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Application $app, Router $router)
{
    if ($app->environment('production')) {
        $this->middlewareAliases['throttle'] = \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequestsWithRedis::class;
    }

    parent::__construct($app, $router);
}
```

Is there a 'standard' way to achieve this without having to override the `Kernel` constructor? Essentially, I would like my app to dynamically choose the relevant middleware dependant on whether the environment is set to `production` (or, the default cache store is set to `redis`).

### Update

The above solution does not work as the Kernel is accessed prior to the app being bootstrapped, thus the environment is not available at this point. The other solution I am now looking into is extending the base `ThrottleRequests` class in order dynamically call the relevant class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much research and testing, I concluded that the best solution was to dynamically set the `throttle` middleware in the `RouteServiceProvider` like so:

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        $this->registerThrottleMiddleware();
    }

    /**
     * Register the middleware used for throttling requests.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function registerThrottleMiddleware(): void
    {
        $router = app()->make('router');

        $middleware = config('cache.default') !== 'redis'
            ? \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class
            : \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequestsWithRedis::class;

        $router->aliasMiddleware('throttle', $middleware);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. I wish this could be defined as a simple config. Someone could try to PR it.